# Dependency property not getting set for datagrid in control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have some requirement to customize datagrid, so i create my own dataGrid extending WPF datagrid. Small relevant code posted below -

```
public class ExtendedDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public ExtendedDataGrid()
    {
        this.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
    }
}
```

I create its instance in a window and set `SelectionMode` to `Single` which works perfectly fine and property gets set to `Single` for the dataGrid. So far all good.

But in case i place my DataGrid in ControlTemplate, `SelectionMode` never gets set to `Single`. SelectionMode is just for example no DP is getting set via XAML if i explicitly set that value in constructor of DataGrid.

Small sample replicating the problem is here -

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <local:ExtendedDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource   
                                                  Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    SelectionMode="Single">
                <local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
                </local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
            </local:ExtendedDataGrid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
    <local:ExtendedDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                          Mode=FindAncestor,
                                          AncestorType=Window}}"
                            Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single">
        <local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
        </local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
    </local:ExtendedDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

For second DataGrid its working fine but not working for DataGrid placed inside ControlTemplate. **Why this weird behaviour? Is it some bug in DataGrid code?**

> **Note** - It will work fine if i comment the line from DataGrid
>   constructor where i am explicitly setting SelectionMode to
>   Extended. I know that's default value and after removing that it
>   will work fine for both cases (also there are many ways to set default value) but i want to know why it works in one case and not in other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after bit of digging code in `PresentationFramework assembly` using `reflector`, i was able to find out the exact RCA for this issue. As mentioned by [nit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19580515/632337), this behaviour is valid for all DP's and for all Controls not just DataGrid.

> This is all to do with [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) that
>   which value is given precedence over other while setting DP's.
>   (Enum is BaseValueSourceInternal which store this precedence order of DP's in WindowsBase.dll assembly)

`DependencyObject class` contains method `UpdateEffectiveValue` which is responsible for setting final actual value on any DP by calling `SetValue` method on DataGrid instance.
`UpdateEffectiveValue` method contains lot of logic before actually calling `SetValue` method on DP.

Interesting check which is stopping from setting it via ControlTemplate is this one (**It checks if new value precedence order is higher than old value precedence order only in that case value will be set on DP otherwise return without setting DP**) -

```
if ((newEntry.BaseValueSourceInternal != BaseValueSourceInternal.Unknown)
    && (newEntry.BaseValueSourceInternal < oldEntry.BaseValueSourceInternal))
{
    return (UpdateResult) 0;
}
```

---

In first case where dataGrid is direct child of window, DP property is set by these steps -

1. WPF engine read BAML(compiled XAML) from top to bottom and once it encounter DataGrid, creates an instance of it.
2. From constructor when we set selection mode DP, `SetValueCommon` method of `DependencyObject` class gets called. It pass on old value and new value to method `UpdateEffectiveValue`.
3. Now, `old value's BaseValueSourceInternal is Unkown` and `new value's BaseValueSourceInternal is set as Local` by SetValueCommon method. Hence, it gets passed from the if check mentioned above and DP gets set.
4. Now, after creating a DataGrid instance, all attributes associated with DataGrid are read from BAML one by one and SetValueCommon method is called on every DP encountered.
5. Since, SetValueCommon method's set `new value with BaseValueSourceInternal.Local` and `old value is already BaseValueSourceInternal.Local`. So precedence order is same, that's why Single value gets set on DP.

---

In second case where DataGrid is placed inside ControlTemplate -

1. DataGrid is not created when WPF engine is reading BAML since it is contained inside a ContentControl. It will be created only when ContentControl is rendered on GUI. `Framework's ApplyTemplate gets called which calls LoadContent method to load the template`.
2. LoadContent internally calls much more methods which at last create an instance of DataGrid and set DP like in previous case which set current value set with BaseValueSourceInternal.Local.
3. Now, once dataGrid instance is created `ApplyTemplatedParentValue` method gets called which tries to set all the DP's found on it by calling method `UpdateEffectiveValue`.
4. `Current value set on DP is set with BaseValueSourceInternal.Local` but `new value` which it tries to set is set as `BaseValueSourceInternal.ParentTemplate`.
5. So, finally when it goes to method `UpdateEffectiveValue`, the if condition mentioned above fails since `ParentTemplate precedence order is lower than Local`. Hence, SetValue never gets called on DP with new value which is a reason than when we comment the line from constructor it's working fine since old value's BaseValueSourceInternal is Unknown and new value's BaseValueSourceInternal is ParentTemplate.

---

As mentioned in the [DP's precedence order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) that property set via animation holds more preference than Local value. So, ideally if we set the property in ControlTemplate via animation, it should work fine. I tried it out and it works completely fine -

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <local:ExtendedDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                       Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
         <local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
         </local:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
         <local:ExtendedDataGrid.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectionMode">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                              Value="{x:Static DataGridSelectionMode.Single}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
          </local:ExtendedDataGrid.Triggers>
    </local:ExtendedDataGrid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your findings :)

Answer (score 2):

This is good question and to answer it requires the insight of how WPF engine is creating these two instances of `DataGrid`.

For the first instance of `DataGrid` that is the direct child of your `Window`, that instance is created when `InitializeComponents()` from the constructor of `Window` is called. I won't go deeply inside how `InitializeComponents` work, but just a jist is it calls the method `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent()` and `LoadComponent()` loads the `XAML` file that is located at the passed in `URI`, and converts it to an instance of the object that is specified by the root element of the `XAML` file. While doing so, it first calls the default constructor of element to be created and then again set the `DependancyProperties` mentioned in the attribute.

Now, the second instance that you have placed inside the `ControlTemplate`. That instance will be created when `ControlTemplate` will be applied on the element. If you are not applying the `Template`, the instance will never get created. While applying the `Template`, `ControlTemplate.LoadContent()` is called to create the root element of the `ControlTemplate`. Now `LoadContent()` takes the different coarse for creating the `UIElements` defined in the  `controlTemplate`. It does call the default constructor for each elements, but when it comes to setting the `DependancyProperties`, it runs number of checks to decide what would be the property value. In the nutshell, it checks if any value is already set for the particular `DependancyProperty` on the element instance (i.e the value is not default value, it is the local value entry for the instance in the ValueDictionary of the `DependancyObject`) it does not consider the value specified in the xaml. Hence, in this case when `LoadComponents` call the default constructor for the DataGrid, we set the `SelectionModeProperty` value. While loading the content, `ControlTemplate` checks it and return the same value and ignores the value specified in the xaml.

And this is true for all the controls not only `DataGrid`.

Comment: `Extended` is default value than why it's still not applying the value supplied by `XAML`. And do you have any reference (any link) to validate your saying. I also believe its something to do with ContentControl load behaviour but i want to know the exact reason for this behaviour. If you can provide any reference for this, that would be great.

Comment: once you set the DependancyProperty explicitly it has the local value...by default value i mean is the static value that you specify at the time of registering dependancy property

Comment: Very interesting read. I would also be interested in references/links to more documentation if you have them!

Comment: @Sphinxxx unfortunately i dont have any documentation for this... but reflecting ControlTemplate.LoadContent() can give you the insight of how it is creating object and setting properties

Comment: @nit, Sphinxxx - Finally i was able to get the exact reason for the same mentioned in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I can't answer your question as to why it doesn't work when using the `ControlTemplate`, but I can give you a better method for setting a default value for an inherited property in an extended class which could fix your problem.

It is possible to provide new meta data with a default value for an inherited `DependencyProperty` using the `DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata` method. You could set your own default value for the `SelectionMode` property using the `static` constructor like this:

```
static ExtendedDataGrid()
{
    SelectionModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDataGrid), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2));
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

The code will compile if you replace the `SelectionMode` enumeration with the integer that represents the value that you want. I merely used the `SelectionMode.Extended` value (now replaced with its integer value - 2) because that's what *you* used in *your* example.

I suggested this alternative way of setting that default value because you said that your problem would go away if you commented out the line in the constructor where you set the default value of the `SelectionMode` property to `SelectionMode.Extended`. I thought that if you used this to replace that line then your problem might go away.

Comment: First of all your code `won't compile`. Also, default value itself is `Extended` so need to set default value at all. Setting default value is not an issue. I want to know that why it works if dataGrid is not in ControlTemplate. Behaviour should be consistent.

Comment: I already know what you posted here. Instead default value should be `DataGridSelectionMode.Extended`, you was using wrong enumeration type. Moreover, in question i mentioned that i know the way out by commenting out the line but what i need to know the reason that why ContentControl ignoring it altogether.

Comment: This i know will compile already - `ExtendedDataGrid.SelectionModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDataGrid),                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DataGridSelectionMode.Extended));`